# What's an effective way of laying out the main text and photos on a web page?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm currently using Flexbox to lay out the main text and images on [my web pages](http://test.scoe.net/rfox/sccy3/parentsAlcoholPrevention.html).
They way I have it set up works pretty well, with text on the left, photos on the right in wide viewports, and a single column of content on small viewports. But there are downsides: in a small viewport, all the images wind up piled at the bottom instead of intermingled with the text. In wide viewports, I don't have much control over where the images appear vertically, whether they correspond well to the text on the left. Plus, the same ol' two-column layout gets a little repetitive on a large site.

My current approach is this: I created two columns, the first using a flex-basis of 66%, the other 33%. I put the main text in the first flex item, then images in the second. In a wide viewport, I set the flex-direction to row so the text appears on the left, photos appear on the right. In a small viewport, the flex basis on both flex items is set to 100% and the flex-direction is set to column so they stack in a single column.

I'm sure there's a better approach than this

Answer (score 1):

Make a container around all the content, set up each section to have both the text and the image inside it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.item .text {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item .image {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item .image img {
  max-height: 120px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 650px) {
  .item {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      <p>lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      <p>lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="text">
      <p>lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text lorem ipsum more text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to outline this. This looks like an excellent solution.  Much obliged!  :)